# Issue with Helm client certificate

Tags: kubernetes-helm, ibm-cloud-private, helm-tls

Hi I have IBM cloud private cluster up and running.
I try login with cloudctl login https://icp-console.example.co.id
Everything is fine, the last line show me:

**Configuring helm: /root/.helm**
**OK**

But when i try to inspect the certificate generated in /root/.helm/cert.pem:
Certificate Information:
Common Name: admin
Valid From: November 9, 2020
Valid To: February 7, 2021
Issuer: [www.ibm.com](http://www.ibm.com), IBM Cloud Private

It shows me above Information. I would like to know, how to extend the certificate generated from command **cloudctl login**, because its only effective for 3 months ?
If possible I would like to make it 10 years, or maybe never expire.
Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it my self,

1. get certificate cert.pem from helm-tiller-secret,
   oc get secret -n kube-system helm-tiller-secret -o go-template --template="{{.data.crt|base64decode}}"
2. get certificate key.pem from helm-tiller-secret,
   oc get secret -n kube-system helm-tiller-secret -o go-template --template="{{.data.key|base64decode}}"
3. copy and paste it to /root/.helm/cert.pem and /root/.helm/key.pem
4. If you want to, you can also create new secret, if some namespace is required a connection to helm with this command:
   kubectl create secret generic apic-ent-helm-tls --from-file=cert.pem=/root/.helm/cert.pem --from-file=ca.pem=/root/.helm/ca.pem --from-file=key.pem=/root/.helm/key.pem -n